# Help us help you

Tags: discussion

It's been a while since we've had a discussion on here, so let's start one.

What information do you want from people when they ask a question?

Answer (score 2):

## Important

- Operating System and Version

## Useful

- Any edits they have made to configuration files.
- Any software they have installed
- The board revision

Comment: More importantly, what they are trying to do and what their problems are in **clear statements**.